# Overflow: scroll - side scroll off page

Tags: css, overflow

Have a div set with overflow: scroll, but my content runs off the side of the page despite the fact that I had the div's width set as 100%.

```
#main {
     background: #ccc;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: auto;
     margin-top: -8px;
     z-index: 1000;
     padding-top: 4px;
     float: right;
     width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
 }

 #main #chat {
     padding-top: -1px;
     padding-left: 0px;
     margin-left: 210px;
     height: 100%;
     width: auto;
     float: right;
     min-height: 100%;
 }
```

How can I sort this?

Example here: [www.dellserve.co.uk/private](http://www.dellserve.co.uk/private)

Answer (score 1):

You've given `body` a width of 100%, so it will stretch 100% of the screen, not including padding and margins. Your browser gives `body` a default margin:

[image]

(I have 8px in chrome) so your body's width is 100% + left margin + right margin, which is of course more than 100%;

Give your body a margin of 0 and you will be good:

```
body{
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, lovely. Many thanks. Spotted this in some of my older css, must have just skimmed over it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `min-width` property from `body`.It should work